# Substring de una cadena cada carácter especifico

Tags: c#, substring

Estoy recibiendo una cadena de datos por medio de C#, la cadena viene de la siguiente forma;

> string:string:string:

Se que existe la función substring, la cual le puedes indicar que agarre las letras de n posición y que tantas se desea tomar, pero en este caso necesito separar la cadena en diferentes variables, por ejemplo:

```
264.1:On:Emanuel:
```

Debería quedar:

> var1=264.1 ; var2=On ; var3=Emanuel

Cabe aclarar que no se sabe la longitud que tendrá cada cadena, ej. aquí puede ser 264.1 el valor que reciba el string1, pero en la siguiente ocasión puede ser 6.8, ¿Como puedo definir que me separe los `string` por ":" y los almacene en variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función Split(string separador):

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
        string data = "264.1:On:Emanuel:";
        string[] words = data.Split(':');
        string var1,var2,var3;
        var1 = words[0];
        var2 = words[1];
        var3 = words[2];
        Console.WriteLine("var1 ="+var1);
        Console.WriteLine("var2 ="+var2);
        Console.WriteLine("var3 ="+var3);
  }
}
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu solución fue la mejor, en pocos pasos y abierta a poner cualquier caracter de separador, muchas gracias me ayudaste mucho!

Answer (score 4):

Para separar o descomponer tu cadena de texto en función del separador "**:**", puedes utilizar el método `Split()` del tipo `string`.

El código sería el siguiente:

```
   var cadena = "264.1:On:Emanuel:";
   List<string> result = cadena.Split(':').ToList();
```

Obtendrás una lista de string `List<string>` con los valores que quieres recuperar.

Comment: Como buena práctica: Si no vas a insertar nuevos elementos en la `List<string>` no es necesario llamar a `ToList()`, basta con tener el array a mano y saber que tiene elementos.

Answer (score 1):

> > ¿Como puedo definir que me separe los string por ":" y los almacene en variables?

Supongo que te quedarás con las soluciones que te dieron los demás comentarios, debido que, soluciona tu problema de una forma más sencilla y corta, sin embargo, yo te explicaré que con el método [substring](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8) puedes lograr el mismo resultado.

El método [substring](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8) recibe dos parámetros (también puede recibir únicamente uno, porqué está sobrecargado): El índice inicial y la longitud de la subcadena. El problema radica que la longitud de la cadena puede ir variando, por ende, necesitamos crear  un algoritmo que nos permita calcular el índice inicial + la longitud de una subcadena, sin importar que longitud tenga la cadena.

El algoritmo lo podemos plantear de esta manera:

- Necesitaremos de una variable para guardar el índice inicial de la subcadena, es evidente que su valor por defecto será 0.
- Luego recorremos caracter por caracter y a la vez, contamos los caracteres con una variable acumuladora para lograr obtener la longitud de la subcadena, todo esto sucederá hasta encontrar el caracter `:`.
- Cuando encontremos el caracter `:`, es donde llamaremos al método [substring](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8) y le pasaremos el índice inicial (que al comienzo será 0) + la longitud de la subcadena.
- Por último, debemos re-inicializar a 0 la variable acumuladora, debido a que, necesitamos usar esa variable para obtener la longitud de cualquier [substring](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8). También debemos de actualizar el índice inicial de la subcadena, esto se logra con la siguiente ecuación: `indiceInicial = i + 1`. El valor de `i` representa la posición de cada caracter en una cadena. Se le suma `1` a `i` porqué cuando la condición `txt[i] == ':'` se cumpla, `i` tendrá la posición del caracter `:` y a nosotros no nos interesa esa posición, sino, la posición siguiente (coincidirá con el índice inicial del próximo [substring](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8)).

El código en C# sería:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {       
        int startIndex = 0; //guarda el índice inicial del substring.
        int lengthSub = 0; //guarda la longitud del substring.
        int j = 0; 
        string txt = "264.1:On:Emanuel:";
        string[] varx = new string[3];
        for(int i = 0; i != txt.Length; ++i)
        {
            //Si se encontró los dos puntos...
            if(txt[i] == ':')
            {
                //Obtenemos la subcadena y lo guardamos en varx
                varx[j++] = txt.Substring(startIndex, lengthSub);
                //Actualizamos el índice inicial de la subcadena
                startIndex = i + 1;
                //Re-inicializamos la longitud a 0
                lengthSub = 0;
            }
            else
                //Contamos cada caracter para obtener la longitud de la subcadena al momento de encontrar los dos puntos
                ++lengthSub;
        }
        Console.Write("var1: " + varx[0] + " var2: " + varx[1] + " var3: " + varx[2]);
    }
}
```

Puede que mi algoritmo se le haya ido un poco de líneas, pero eso no quiere decir que sea un mal algoritmo. Espero que te sirva.